# Blender 2.74 - problem opening rigged model created in 2.73

Tags: armature

I have encountered a wierd problem. Have created a model in Blender 2.73, rigged with Rigify and animated. Everything works just perfect. Now when I have downloaded the new Blender 2.74 and opened the very same .blend file the model is distorted. Looks like all bones are concentrated around the middle of the model.

This happens only in the Pose mode. In Blender 2.74 Object or Edit modes are working fine i.e. the mesh is displayed in T pose again.

I did try FBX export/import but the result is the same.
I did reset to the Pose to T pose, zeroed IKs for arms & legs then saved the model in 2.73 and opened in 2.74 - did not help.

Any clues what needs to be done ?

Comment: Have you setting up your users preference on the 2.74 version of blender? You need to have auto run python script enabled

Comment: This is what I was missing. Thanks a million user14438 !